# Codeigniter - sharing session between two xampp servers

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Say I have two projects like `projectA` and `projectB` both are deployed in two different PCs both PCs having their own xampp server installed. Both PCs are connected to an internal network.

Suppose a session is started in `projectA` and put some data their. Now if I want to access this session from `projectB` (another PC another server) is it possible and if possible then how ?

Comment: Session will be create on browser!! not in external file

Comment: is it possible ?? @Abdulla

Comment: You could create a shared folder for the two XAMPP installs, one they could each access.  Then you'd have to update the php.ini for each to use that folder for session storage.